# Dataset of weather as it was *forecast* at the time

Tags: data-request, weather

I have been able to find very detailed weather datasets from noaa (ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/). But I realized that for my purposes I can not simply use weather prediction probabilities to get probable weather forecasts of the time.

I need a dataset of dates and what weather people thought that particular date would have days or weeks in advance of it. In other words: actual weather, weather predicted 1d ago, 2d ago, 3d ago, ... 2 weeks ago (or something).

Does such a dataset exist? I fully anticipate that this is too niche and possibly not public. If so, would anyone know if it's possible to rerun a climate model to generate accurate weather forecasts of the time? Or are such algorithms proprietary?

Comment: My understanding is that NOAA weather models are archived for a short period of time, but not at the same level of detail as what they're run at.  If you have the input data/parameters, it should be possible to re-run them.  The issue is that it might not be possible to identify what data was available at the time the model was originally run .... and then there's always human evaluation of the models (and then orders to run specific areas in higher detail).  I don't have time to dig now, but try starting at : https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/data-access/model-data

Comment: do you consider farmers almanac weather data? also, i don't see an open data solution to that...but you could buy it

Answer (score 5):

We have the data you are asking for in our regional Open Data portal (Basque Country, Spain), so I guess you could have it without purchasing it. I do not know how NOAA works, but here, you could send a message to the people in charge of the Open Data portal and they always answer your demands.

Comment: I think this is the data set http://opendata.euskadi.eus/catalogo/-/prediccion-meteorologica-de-2016/ The zipped XML folder has historical forecasts http://opendata.euskadi.eus/contenidos/ds_meteorologicos/forecast_ds_2016/opendata/data_forecast_ds_2016.zip