# Historical USA weather forecasts

Tags: data-request, weather, historical

I'm looking for a historical USA (specifically Chicago, IL) weather forecast dataset. Temperature forecasts would suffice, though the more data, the merrier. I know this has been asked a lot of times in the past, but nothing worked for me. Here's what I found so far:

- Both links in the accepted answer to [this question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/2009/historical-weather-forecasts) are broken
- [DarkSky API](https://darksky.net/dev/docs/faq) can't provide historical forecasts, but only historical observations and future forecasts
- [NOAA's Weather Prediction Center archives](https://www.wpc.ncep.noaa.gov/archives/web_pages/wpc_arch/get_wpc_archives.php) only provide pictures (either GIFs or PDFs), with no textual temperature forecast data
- The data in [this question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6077/dataset-of-weather-as-it-was-forecast-at-the-time) doesn't seem to suit my needs (not sure how to parse some of it, and the parts that I have been able to parse don't contain historical Chicago forecasts). The answer to that question is relevant only to Europe, and I need USA weather forecasts
- The best thing I could find was [NOAA's Archive Information Request System](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/has/HAS.StationYearSelect?datasetname=9957ANX&subqueryby=STATION&applname=SRRSBTNSEL&outdest=APPS&dtypesort=dtypeord&stationsort=id) and [Iowa State Mesonet](http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/wx/afos/#). Both provided historical weather forecasts for Chicago, but they were both very coarse and verbal. For example, the following paragraph appears in a huge text file: ".TODAY...Cloudy. Showers likely in the morning, then a chance of showers in the afternoon. Highs around 70. Northeast winds 10 to 20 mph. Chance of precipitation 60 percent." This thing would be difficult to parse, and would probably not be worth it because it just says "Highs **around 70**".

So is there anywhere from which I could get historical data that:
1. Contains Chicago temperature forecasts
2. Is easy to parse (e.g. in csv format)

Comment: I fixed the dead links in https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/2013/1511, please let us know if it's useful

Comment: Thanks, but none of the sites contained historical weather forecasts for Chicago (in a format that is easy to parse). Moreover, I've contacted NOAA's support, and they said they don't have CSV/JSON/any other "nice" format for this kind of things.

Comment: *This is not an answer. I am just typing my question here since I am not able to comment. I will delete this soon* Since its been a while, I am just curious to know if you found an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

One free source of forecasted temperatures for the [PJM](https://www.pjm.com/about-pjm/who-we-are.aspx) electricity market is the regional transmission operator (PJM). Unfortunately, you are limited to data beginning July 1, 2018 and based on PJM's [zones](https://www.pjm.com/library/%7E/media/about-pjm/pjm-zones.ashx): https://dataminer2.pjm.com/feed/da_tempset/definition

[image]

PJM does offer a free API, although there is a simple registration process.

Data service providers such as [MarketView](https://www.marketview.com/) have NOAA's historical weather forecasts for several hundred airports. However, the most affordable option is about $300 per month and that doesn't include an API feed (much more expensive). MarketView does offer an Excel add-in so that could work if you don't mind importing an Excel file into your program (e.g., python script). Also offers a free 14-day trial. Here is an interface from the Excel add-in for NOAA weather forecasts:[image: MarketView weather forecast]

Answer (score 0):

Some data seems to be available here:
https://www.weather.gov/wrh/climate?wfo=lot

You have to choose the location, then your desired target climate variable, select the applicable date option and then press "View". Depending on the options you have chosen, the data is presented either in tabular or in graphical views.

Answer (score -1):

openweathermap.org provides historical forecasts by location for the past 3 years. You purchase the data by location and 3 years of historical forecasts that you can download immediately is available for $45 dollars I believe. I searched long and hard for somebody that provided historical forecasts. Everyone provides historical weather but not the forecasts. Even the US government through NOAA starts purging forecasts after 90 days.

Comment: hardly open data, despite their domain name having "open" and ".org"

Comment: I agree. The cost is not the best but it provides exactly what the person is asking for in csv format. Seems like he may have been looking for a long time for exactly what openweathermap.org is providing for a fee. I have also looked for a long time for this type of data and to me the $45 dollars was worth it for me to be able to move forward as opposed to being stuck forever.